# How to decrease Query time of this Query with InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize this query. Now it takes 28 seconds.

**AS** used to be missing in my query. After adding, query time dropped 20%

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    g.adresid,
    g.senaryoid,
    g.olayid,
    g.gonderilecegitarih
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            adresid
        FROM
            expose2.800_emsenaryolar_emgidenbulten
        WHERE
            olayid = '3320'
    ) AS s
RIGHT JOIN expose2.800_emsenaryolar_emgidenbulten AS g ON s.adresid = g.adresid
WHERE
    s.adresid IS NULL
AND g.olayid = '2784'
AND g.durum = '1'
AND g.gonderilecegitarih < DATE_SUB(
    '2015-05-13 15:40:15',
    INTERVAL 1 DAY
)
```

Comment: `AS` is only syntactic sugar.  Any difference in speed came from caching and/or external activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `s.adresid IS NULL` condition in  subquery it will join faster then more rows ...

```
SELECT
    g.id,
    g.adresid,
    g.senaryoid,
    g.olayid,
    g.gonderilecegitarih
FROM (
        SELECT adresid FROM expose2.800_emsenaryolar_emgidenbulten WHERE olayid = '3320' and  s.adresid IS NULL
    ) AS s
RIGHT JOIN expose2.800_emsenaryolar_emgidenbulten AS g ON s.adresid = g.adresid

AND g.olayid = '2784'
AND g.durum = '1'
AND g.gonderilecegitarih < DATE_SUB(
    '2015-05-13 15:40:15',
    INTERVAL 1 DAY
)
```

still this query optimized using self join.

Comment: s.adresid cannot be inside since 'AS s' is defined afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

For added speed, add this composite index to `g`:

```
INDEX(olayid, durum, gonderilecegitarih)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE 800_emsenaryolar_emgidenbulten`; I want to verify that you also have an index on `adresid`.